# How does Boto3 make connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

Does Boto3 use a particular protocol to make connections? If two resources are within the same region (or same availability zone), will connections between them still be made over the internet? Or will Boto3 connect through a local network. Are there situations in which another connection method (e.g. HTTP, SSH, etc) will improve network performance?

Comment: AWS service API requests are HTTPS (or HTTP). They're made to public API endpoints. If made from a compute node within an AWS region, I'd expect them to stay on the AWS backbone. What are you hoping to do here?

Comment: I want the best design patterns for cloud architectures. It's not clear to me if Boto3 should be used for inter-resource communication, or if Boto3 should be limited to resource allocation/de-allocation, setting permissions, managing users, etc. For example, should uploads from EC2 to S3 use Boto3 or the REST API?

Comment: I think you'd have to decide if going direct to the REST API provided some compelling advantage for you (perhaps around total executable size or added latency of the SDK layer). In most cases, in my opinion, it would not outweigh the programmer productivity benefits associated with a well-supported SDK like boto3. I've worked with 100s of people programming against AWS, and not one of them chose to use the REST APIs directly. I've also written and maintained software using the REST APIs (without the help of an SDK) and it's significantly more work (you end up writing a mini-SDK).

Comment: I don't think that the REST API provide any better security than using the API endpoints. They both connect to service endpoints "on the Internet". If you wish to avoid traffic going on the Internet (including the AWS backbone), you can create a VPC Endpoint for the desired service _within the VPC_. This will direct API requests over the VPC Endpoint rather than exiting the VPC and going over the Internet.